# How to email Rendered Report in diffrent formats like pdf,excel,word in Report Viewer in Local Mode and Modify Tool bar of Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue related with Report viewer control Version=10.0.0.0
i am showing SSRS Report(.rdl) file on report viewer in Local Mode.
I have following problems in Find Control of report viewer,

1. When I search any text in rendered report and if text found but my report shift to upside and to click on find next
   user have to scroll again and again.
2. After Last occurrence of searched text when we click on find next the message shown and text box of find control will be blank
   but i want the text should not blank. How can i do it.

I want to know that how much control we have in report viewer's Find Control.